# Non-blocking way to read from a Pipe

Tags: go

I want to create a simple app which will be reading continuously output from one app, process it and write processed output to stdout. This app can produce a lot of data within a second and next is silent for a few minutes.

The problem is that mine data processing algorithm is quite slow so main loop is blocked. When the loop is blocked I'm loosing a data which comes and this moment.

```golang
    cmd := exec.Command("someapp")
    stdoutPipe, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    stdoutReader := bufio.NewReader(stdoutPipe)

    go func() {
        bufioReader := bufio.NewReader(stdoutReader)
        for {
            output, _, err := bufioReader.ReadLine()
            if err != nil || err == io.EOF {
                break
            }

            processedOutput := dataProcessor(output);

            fmt.Print(processedOutput)
        }
    }()
```

Probably the best way to solve this problem is to buffer all output and process it in another Goroutine but I'm not sure how to implement this in Golang. What is the most idiomatic way to solve this problem?

Comment: You start a goroutine with the `go` keyword, but you obviously already know that. So what do you have trouble with, exactly?

Comment: I know that I can start dataProcessor(output) in goroutine but I'm not sure if spawning like 2000 goroutines in a second to proces every single line is a good idea. I would prefer to put all lines in some queue and process this queue in second goroutine. There is also second problem with goroutine, they don't guarantee me correct order.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting to create one goroutine per line. Send the lines to a single goroutine that does the processing using a buffered channels. If channels are new to you, see [The Tour](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2) and maybe [Go by Example](https://gobyexample.com/channels)

Answer (score 1):

You can have two goroutines, one is a supplier, the other a consumer. The supplier executes a command and passes data to the consumer through a channel.

```go
cmd := exec.Command("someapp")
stdoutPipe, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
stdoutReader := bufio.NewReader(stdoutPipe)
Datas := make(chan Data, 100)
go dataProcessor(Datas)
    bufioReader := bufio.NewReader(stdoutReader)
    for {
        output, _, err := bufioReader.ReadLine()
        var tempData Data
        tempData.Out = output
        if err != nil || err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        Datas <- tempData
        }
}
```

And then you will process data in `dataProcessor` function:

```go
func dataProcessor(Datas <-chan Data)  {
    for  {
        select {
        case data := <-Datas:
        fmt.Println(data)
        default:
            continue
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, it is a very simple example, and you should customize it and make it better. Search about channels and goroutines. Reading [this](https://gobyexample.com/channels) tutorial could be helpful.

Comment: Can you please format your code nicely? Also, in `for true` loop `true` is not needed and `continue` inside select won't work, better to use `return` here.

Comment: @MaximKosov Won't return end the select prematurely if there is nothing to be read from `Datas` for a while, missing if something comes later? It should only return when the channel is closed, shouldn't it? As I understand it, the return case is unneccesary here because it will block on the read of `Datas` channel either way. @all Is that correct?

Comment: @xuiqzy this is a pretty old topic. `default: continue` is not needed here at all, and it should return when Datas is closed. So, better just use `for range` syntax.  I don't know why I proposed to use return initially. Maybe I misunderstood the intention originally.